# Finding element of a given rank in an arbitrary array

Tags: algorithm, rank

What I am is doing is using a quicksort algorithm, so that my pivot element(which will always be the first element of the array gets positioned to its appropriate position in the sorted array and I am calling this method again until I do not position the element at a given rank. Is there a better solution?

Here is my code:

```
public static int arbitrary(int a[],int x,int y,int rank)//x and y are first and last indecies of the array
{
    int j=y,temp;
    if(x<y)
    {
        for(int i=y;i>x;i--)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[x])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
                j--;
            }
        }
        temp=a[x];
        a[x]=a[j];
        a[j]=temp;
        //System.out.println("j is "+j);
        if(j==rank)
            return a[j];
        else if(rank<j)
            return arbitrary(a,x,j-1,rank);
        else
            return arbitrary(a,j+1,y,rank);
    }
    else
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by element of a rank?

Comment: If by "rank" you mean "the element's position in the array if you sorted it", construct a [minheap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) and use it to find the Nth largest element.

Comment: @Kevin yes that's what I call rank.Can you please elaborate your answer as I am not getting it completely how minheap can help me because what I can know  after building minheap is that all the largest n/2 elements are in the leaf and nothing else...And thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you have implemented is called [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).
Just select a random pivot and to get rid of the worst case with O(n²) time complexity.
The expected runtime is now about `3.4n + o(n)`.
Quickselect is probably the best tradeoff between performance and simplicity.

An even more advanced pivot selection strategy results in `1.5n + o(n)` expected time
([Floyd-Rivest Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Rivest_algorithm)).

**Fun Fact**: With deterministic algorithms you can't go better than `2n`. [BFPRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) for example needs about `2.95n` to select the median.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to find Rank element by using the QuickSort method:

> - In QuickSort, at every iteration you are able to get fixed one pivot element.
> - When the RankElement == PivotIndex, and break the condition and    return the value.

```
public class FindRank {
 public void find(int[] arr, int low, int high, int k) {
    if (low < high) {
        int pivot = partition(arr, low, high, k);
        find(arr, low, pivot - 1, k);
        find(arr, pivot + 1, high, k);
    }
}

public int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high, int k) {
    int pivotIndex = high;
    while (low < high) {
        while (low < high && arr[low] <= arr[pivotIndex]) {
            low++;
        }
        while (low > high && arr[high] >= arr[pivotIndex]) {
            high--;
        }
        if (low < high) {
            swap(arr, low, high);
        }
    }
    swap(arr, pivotIndex, high);
    if (pivotIndex == k) {
        System.out.println("Array Value:" + arr[k] + " index:" + k);
        return k;
    }
    return high;
}

private void swap(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    int temp = arr[low];
    arr[low] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;
 }
}
```